# Negative Floating Point Numbers

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a situation where I need to pass negative floating-point number to an imported DPI-C function in SystemVerilog.

Below is pseudocode that I'm running but somehow it doesn't print a negative floating point number.

```
bit [5:0] a;
real      b;

b = (a[5] * -1) + (a[4] * 0.5) + (a[3] * 0.25) + (a[2] * 0.125) + (a[1] * 0.0625) + (a[0] * 0.03125)
`uvm_info(get_name(), $sformatf("value of b is: %.5f", b), UVM_MEDIUM)
```

For, `6'b111110`

It prints,
`4294967295.93750`
instead of `-0.03125`

After calculating negative floating-point number, I need to pass it to a DPI-C function as `real`

Do you know what's wrong here?

I also tried taking 2's complement of b and then called `$rtoi`, divide integer by `scaling factor of 5`. But it results in 0.00000 as value of b is very small i.e -0.03125

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-1` is interpreted as (I believe) a 32-bit integer.  Use `-1.0` for a real (floating-point) value:

```
module tb;

bit [5:0] a;
real      b;

initial begin
    a = 6'b111110;
    b = (a[5] * -1.0) + (a[4] * 0.5) + (a[3] * 0.25) + (a[2] * 0.125) + (a[1] * 0.0625) + (a[0] * 0.03125);
    #1;
    $display("value of b is: %.5f", b);
end

endmodule
```

Prints:

```
value of b is: -0.06250
```

I get this output on 2 different simulators.